# "H.E. Donald J. Trump" in Apec 2017 - H.E stands for?

Tags: abbreviations

[image: "H.E. Donald J. Trump" in Apec 2017]

I have scratched my head and think but don't know what "H.E" stands for in this situation, I guess Host Environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***H.E.*** stands for ***His Excellency***. This is just a type of honorary title used to address government officials like presidents, envoys, ambassadors et cetera during official visits, presidential summits and the like. For female dignitaries, you would say ***Her Excellency***. This is, however, not practiced in western countries. For more information about this expression, take a look at its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellency#International_diplomacy).